# Как установить APK?

Tags: java, android, adb

Как установить APK в сайлент режиме? то есть в невидимом режиме, БЕЗ РУТ.

```
Process  install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/busybox pm install " + "/sdcard/test.apk");
```

Данный код не работает. То есть в ответ я получаю 1. Но apk установленной не вижу.

Comment: есть решение на английском с кодом, но долго переводит http://stackoverflow.com/a/14955033/4953620

Comment: @Saidolim этот способ только если есть root

Comment: Тогда предложите другой способ где без рута можно такое провернуть?

Comment: Да вы, батенька, троян делаете. Но если по делу, то решение есть, даже без ROOT, т.к. сам один раз загнался этим, чтобы подшутить над  другом, ответ не скажу, а то ваш троян покорит мир, лишь могу сподвигнуть к решению, вам поможет рефлексия

Comment: Будь так, то тогда почему тот человек который это придумал, установку без рута до сих пор своим трояном мир не покорил? 

Судя по вашему комменту мне кажется что вы и сами не знаете ответа на сей вопрос, но так как оставили коммент то решили якобы выдать себя за умного человека и что будто сей процесс можно осуществить через рефлексацию.

P.S. 
При чем тут рефлексация и Runtime, вы не в себе батенька

Comment: никак. Это, слава Богу, невозможно

Comment: @metalurgus, А на карте я могу допустим переименовывать файлы, перекиыдывать таким обращзозм с одной в другую папку.

Дак почему же в /data/app нет доступа?

Comment: @xTIGRx, поумолчанию нет доступа. Система его не дает.

Comment: @metalurgus, Ясно

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы этот способ работал нужно чтобы APK было подписано как системное и добавить в манифест permission `android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES`.

Comment: Не работает даже так

Comment: А как ты подписал приложение как системное?

Comment: Не понял, можно чуток подробнее? Я добавил в манифест это разрешение и эффекта нуль

Comment: Написано в документации: Not for use by third-party applications. Так что только если будете свою прошивку делать.